# Using ARKit 2.0's AREnvironmentProbeAnchor.environmentTexture in Unity to generate reflection probes

Tags: c#, ios, swift, unity-game-engine, arkit

I'm playing around with ARKit 2.0 beta. I see that when I enable environment texturing, the `AREnvironmentProbeAnchor`'s that are added to the scene have a `environmentTexture` field which is a `MTLTexture`, and represents the actual cube map that will be used as environment maps. When I look at this texture from Quick View, I see that it has 6 different images for each direction, but how is this represented in the memory? How can I access each image separately and use them for whatever?

What I'm trying to do is pass this `MTLTexture` to Unity and use it there on a reflection probe, but I need to know how this texture is represented and how to use it. Any information on this is appreciated.

Comment: Unity appears to have [some docs](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/unity-arkit-plugin/src/arkit2.0_beta/docs/WhatsNewInARKit2_0.md?fileviewer=file-view-default) on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @rickster's suggestion, I had a look at the ARKit 2.0 Unity plugin's implementation, and I managed to actually use the `AREnvironmentProbeAnchor.environmentTexture` inside my Unity scene.

`MTLTexture` has a property named `textureType`, which is an enum value and is `.typeCubeArray` for the texture returned by `AREnvironmentProbeAnchor.environmentTexture`. This is explained thoroughly on the `MTLTexture` [documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexture).

A `MTLTexture` having a `texturetype` of type `.typeCubeArray` means that when you pass the pointer to this `MTLTexture` to the Unity side, you can use it to create a `Cubemap`, which you can then use as your reflection probes environment texture. Here's how things roughly work on the Unity side:

```
// You can pass the pointer to your MTLTexture as an IntPtr to the Unity side
[DllImport("__Internal")]
public static extern IntPtr GetEnvironmentTexture();

void AddNewProbe() 
{
    var texturePtr = GetEnvironmentTexture();
    if (texturePtr == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        continue;
    }

    var cubemap = Cubemap.CreateExternalTexture(0, TextureFormat.R8, false, texturePtr);
    var probeComponent = AddComponent<ReflectionProbe>();
    probeComponent.customBakedTexture = cubemap;
}
```

And on the iOS side, you just need to have a method with the name you declared on the Unity side, which returns a pointer to your `MTLTexture`. Its return type can be `void*` or `id<MTLTexture>`, both of them works fine. This method should be placed on your Unity bridge for it to be visible to the Unity side.

```
extern "C" void* GetEnvironmentTexture() {
    AREnvironmentProbeAnchor* anchor = [self updatedEnvironmentProbeAnchor];
    return (__bridge_retained void*) [anchor environmentTexture];
}
```

You can (and frankly, should) modify and improve this to fit your needs.